# Constant current LED driver - lowering brightness with dip switches

Tags: led-driver

Having a 28W LED lamp with constant current LED driver which has some dip switches where I can change the current, is it safe to lower the current to reduce the brightness of the LED?

Comment: I'm inclined to say yes. But to make sure there's no hidden caveats, perhaps you could update your post with information about the LED lamp and driver. (make, model, datasheet...)

Comment: the lamp is a Caboche PLUS Grande LED, i can't see what type the LED's are (built into the lamp); the LED driver is a TCI Professionale 42 BI https://win.tcisaronno.com/downloads/?IDnode=3118&field=docs&language=EN ..

Comment: Datasheet does not have info how to set DIP switch to dedicated current. Check out for additional documents, like manual, installation guide, etc.

Comment: the dip switch settings are written on the LED driver going from 300 mA (OFF OFF OFF OFF) to 1050 mA (ON ON ON ON) .. with 50 mA intervals

Answer (score 1):

I would think so, yes.

The constant-current driver [Professionale 42 BI 127486](https://win.tcisaronno.com/downloads/?IDnode=3118&field=docs&language=EN) states that it will work up to 1050mA output. That is the maximum it can deliver; whether you use all of that or not, is up to you.

As a side benefit, the LEDs will last even longer when under-powered.

However they could, if run dimly enough, appear to color-shift slightly.  The only way to know if this will happen would be to try it.

Comment: Yes. Agree. No harm to leds by decreasing current.